# GitHub Action: Accessing a Server from GitHub via SSH

Tags: github, ssh, deployment, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a shell script that can connect to my server. It executes some shell commands there. Now I want to integrate the script into my GitHub action workflow. I have put the script in my repository and the script is also started. But I don't have any ssh commands yet, only echo commands in the script. Therefore it runs successfully.

Now I want to add the SSH commands to the script. But I wonder how I should handle the SSH key now. As I understand it, GitHub does not have a private key from which I can generate my public key and then store it on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using the GitHub Action [`appleboy/ssh-action`](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action)

Executing remote ssh commands.

```yaml
name: remote ssh command
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        script: whoami
```

You can register your private key and other sensitive data as [GitHub secret for your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository).